# system errors in theme

Tags: php, logging

getting some system errors as below, im trying to work out why the frontend does not log in using IE or safari, but from the logs im slowly working through issues, any ideas on this one, the errors are line 51, 54 and 67,

```
2015-05-12T13:46:34+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/mtorion/default/template/magenthemes/mainmenu/top.phtml on line 51
2015-05-12T13:46:34+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/mtorion/default/template/magenthemes/mainmenu/top.phtml on line 54
2015-05-12T13:46:34+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/mtorion/default/template/magenthemes/mainmenu/top.phtml on line 67
```

And here is my code:

```
    <?php
/**
 *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * @category     MT
 * @package      MT_Themes
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * @copyright    Copyright (C) 2008-2013 MagentoThemes.net. All Rights Reserved.
 * @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later;
 * @author       MagentoThemes.net
 * @email        support@magentothemes.net
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 */
?>
<!-- navigation BOF -->
<?php
$theme = $this->helper('mtorion');
$sticky_logo = $theme->getCfg('header/sticky_logo');
$megaeffect = Mage::getStoreConfig('mtorion/menu/effect');
$_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(FALSE, FALSE, 0, 'level-top', 'sub-wrapper' );
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="mt-navigation hidden-xs">
    <?php
    $logoSrc = $this->getSkinUrl($sticky_logo);
    $logoArc = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt');
    ?>
    <div class="logo-sticky" style="display: none;">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
            <img class="img-sticky img-responsive" src="<?php echo $logoSrc; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logoArc; ?>" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-main-menu">
        <ul id="mtnav" class="megamenu">
            <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('mtorion/menu/home')){?>
            <li class="level0 home level-top <?php if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {echo " active";}?> m-dropdown parent">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>" class="level-top"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></span></a>
            </li> 
            <?php }?>
            <?php
            echo $_menu;
            if(Mage::getStoreConfig('mtorion/menu/enable_custom')){
                $getidentifier = Mage::getStoreConfig('mtorion/menu/static_identifier');
                $arrayidentifier = explode(";", $getidentifier);
                foreach($arrayidentifier as $mcustom){
                    $static_block = explode(':', $mcustom);
                    $custom_menu = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($static_block[0]);
                    if($static_block[1]) $class = 'menu-item-'.$static_block[1];
                    if($custom_menu->getIsActive()) {
                        echo '
                        <li class="level0 level-top parent custom-block '.$class.'">
                            <a href="#" class="level-top">
                                <span>'.$custom_menu->getTitle().'</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="sub-wrapper">'.$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($static_block[0])->toHtml().'</div>
                        </li>';
                    }
                } 
                $urlkey = Mage::getStoreConfig('mtorion/menu/url_key');
                $arrayUrlKey = explode(";", $urlkey);
                foreach($arrayUrlKey as $url){
                    $condition = explode(':', $url);
                    $page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($condition[0], 'identifier');
                    if($condition[1]) $class = 'menu-item-'.$condition[1];
                    if($page->getIsActive()) {
                ?> 
                    <li class="level0 level-top parent custom-block <?php if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == $page->getIdentifier()) {echo " active";}?> <?php echo $class;?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($condition[0]);?>" class="level-top">
                            <span><?php echo $page->getTitle();?></span>
                        </a> 
                    </li> 
                <?php 
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $mt(function(){
        $mt(".megamenu").megamenu({
            'animation':'<?php echo $megaeffect;?>',
            'mm_timeout': 150
        });
    });
</script>
<?php endif ?>
<!-- navigation EOF -->
```

Comment: sorry I cannot see whats changed, im not used to this so copied everything and pasted into the existing and it all went wrong